# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not cupy.core.core.ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, object-detection, nms, cupy

In object detection algorithms, Non-Maximum Suppression(NMS) is used to discard extra detection results for an object e.g. a vehicle.

Normally, horizontal bounding boxes are used in object detection algorithms and the GPU implementation of horizontal NMS already exists, but I wanted to have GPU implementation of rotated bounding boxes.

The CPU implementation has been already done, but I am struggling to convert CPU version to GPU version using CuPy package. Here is the code I have written. After the code section, you can see the error.

My question is what is the reason of TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not cupy.core.core.ndarray?

```
    from shapely.geometry import Polygon as shpoly
    import time
    
    #### CPU implementation
    import numpy as np   
    
    def polygon_iou(poly1, poly2):
      """
      Intersection over union between two shapely polygons.
      """
      if not poly1.intersects(poly2): # this test is fast and can accelerate calculation
        iou = 0
      else:
        try:
          inter_area = poly1.intersection(poly2).area
          union_area = poly1.area + poly2.area - inter_area
          iou = float(inter_area) / float(union_area)
        except shapely.geos.TopologicalError:
          warnings.warn("'shapely.geos.TopologicalError occured, iou set to 0'", UserWarning)
          iou = 0
        except ZeroDivisionError:
          iou = 0
      return iou
    
    def polygon_from_array(poly_):
      """
      Create a shapely polygon object from gt or dt line.
      """
      polygon_points = np.array(poly_).reshape(4, 2)
      polygon = shpoly(polygon_points).convex_hull
      return polygon
    
    def nms(dets, thresh):
        scores = dets[:, 8]
        order = scores.argsort()[::-1]
        polys = []
        areas = []
        for i in range(len(dets)):
            tm_polygon = polygon_from_array(dets[i,:8])
            polys.append(tm_polygon)
        keep = []
        while order.size > 0:
            ovr = []
            i = order[0]
            keep.append(i)
            for j in range(order.size - 1):
                iou = polygon_iou(polys[i], polys[order[j + 1]])
                ovr.append(iou)
            ovr = np.array(ovr)
            inds = np.where(ovr <= thresh)[0]
            order = order[inds + 1]
        return keep
    
    
    #### GPU implementation
    import cupy as cp  
      
    def polygon_iou_gpu(poly1, poly2):
      """
      Intersection over union between two shapely polygons.
      """
      if not poly1.intersects(poly2): # this test is fast and can accelerate calculation
        iou = 0
      else:
        try:
          inter_area = poly1.intersection(poly2).area
          union_area = poly1.area + poly2.area - inter_area
          iou = float(inter_area) / float(union_area)
        except shapely.geos.TopologicalError:
          warnings.warn("'shapely.geos.TopologicalError occured, iou set to 0'", UserWarning)
          iou = 0
        except ZeroDivisionError:
          iou = 0
      return iou
    
    def polygon_from_array_gpu(poly_):
      """
      Create a shapely polygon object from gt or dt line.
      """
      polygon_points = cp.array(poly_).reshape(4, 2)
      polygon = shpoly(polygon_points).convex_hull
      return polygon
    
    def nms_gpu(dets, thresh):
        scores = dets[:, 8]
        order = scores.argsort()[::-1]
        polys = []
        areas = []
        for i in range(len(dets)):
            tm_polygon = polygon_from_array_gpu(dets[i,:8])
            polys.append(tm_polygon)
        keep = []
        while order.size > 0:
            ovr = []
            i = order[0]
            keep.append(i)
            for j in range(order.size - 1):   
                iou = polygon_iou_gpu(polys[i], polys[order[j + 1]])
                ovr.append(iou)
            ovr = np.array(ovr)
            inds = np.where(ovr <= thresh)[0]
            order = order[inds + 1]
        return keep
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import random
        boxes = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000,8))
        scores = np.random.rand(1000, 1)
        dets = np.hstack((boxes, scores[:])).astype(np.float32)

    
        thresh = 0.1
        start = time.time()
        keep = nms(dets, thresh)
        print("CPU implementation took: {}".format(time.time() - start))
    
        cp.cuda.Device(1)
        dets_gpu = cp.array(dets)
        start = time.time()
        keep = nms_gpu(dets_gpu, thresh)
        print("GPU implementation took: {}".format(time.time() - start))
```

The error is

> CPU implementation took: 0.3672311305999756
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "nms_rotated.py", line 117, in
>
> ```
> keep = nms_gpu(dets_gpu, thresh)
> ```
>
> File "nms_rotated.py", line 97, in nms_gpu
>
> ```
> iou = polygon_iou_gpu(polys[i], polys[order[j + 1]])
> ```
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not cupy.core.core.ndarray

Update: 13.02.2019
I tried @Yuki Hashimoto's answer

by replacing `iou = polygon_iou_gpu(polys[i], polys[order[j + 1]])` with             `iou = polygon_iou_gpu(polys[i.get()], polys[order[j + 1].get()])`. It does not throw any errors, but the GPU version is multiple times slower than CPU version.

by using 100000 random detections:

> ```
>       CPU implementation took: 47.125494956970215
>       GPU implementation took: 142.08464860916138
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In very short: use PFN's official [non-maximum suppression](https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/blob/master/chainercv/utils/bbox/non_maximum_suppression.py).

Details:
Use `cp.where`, which returns a `list` object which matches some condition.

---

The `corochann`'s answer is not recommended, because `polys` is a list, and `list` should not be sliced by `np.ndarray` either. (and injecting another dependency is not recommended...)

```
>>> polys[order.get()]  # get method returns np.ndarray
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
>>> polys[order[j + 1].get()]
### some result in some case, but this may fails depending on your env.###
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked the implementation of NMS in chainer, but it is for horizontal bounding box. As I have mentioned in the question, NMS for horizontal bounding boxes have been already several time implemented, but for rotated bounding box there is no CUDA accelerated NMS. I tried to remove the dependency of the code for Shapely, but could not an easy way to find out intersection of two polygons and computing their areas for the sake of Intersection over Union computation.

Comment: I tried your answer. It worked, but the speed of GPU is much slower than CPU with 10000 random detections.

Comment: There are two reasons. First, in your code, the data is switching back and forward between CPU and GPU. For example, the `Polygon` class is implemented as an array on CPU, so to use cupy, it must be transported to GPU. This is also observed in `order.get()`, which sequentially (important!) get the value, which is not suitable operation for GPU. Second, in the PFN's official example, the NMS is directly implemented by CUDA-C, and uses shared memory to fast memory access (and also to parallelize the sequential operation I mentioned above). Writing NMS in GPU-parallelism is very difficult.

Comment: It should be noted that CPU is FASTER than GPU in almost all cases. ONLY GRAPHICS or MATRIX MATH is faster in GPU (vast parallelism is one of the exceptions).

Comment: NMS for horizontal bounding box with GPU implementation is multiple times faster than CPU implementation. I am going to achieve the same speed up for the rotated bounding box. I think still GPU implementation should be faster than CPU one as NMS operation generally has not changed much.

Comment: To speed up it, you have to get rid of sharply.Polygon, because it only works on CPU. I think the CPU-GPU transportation is the bottle-neck, so if you are familiar with the parallel-computation algorithms for union/intersection computation, you might be able to speed up it, although it is much more complicated for the general polygon than vertical/horizontal rectangle.

Comment: Okay. thanks. So I think generally the question is answered, but I couldn't achieve what I was hoping for. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with CUDA and parallel algorithms. And I tried to compute the intersection of two polygons and their area which I found to be complicated and couldn't manage it.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE 2019/2/13]

Please refer @yuki-hashimoto 's answer, which is more suitable.

---

As written in the error message

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not cupy.core.core.ndarray

I guess the `order` is cupy array?
In that case `polys[order[j + 1]]` is using indices `order[j+1]` as cupy array which may cause the problem.
How about try converting them to numpy array by `cuda.to_cpu(array)` method?

```
from chainer import cuda
iou = polygon_iou_gpu(polys[i], polys[cuda.to_cpu(order[j + 1])])
```

Comment: converting it to numpy array is actually moving towards CPU implementation. The goal is to speed up using CuPy.

Comment: It only send index `order` to GPU, which is quite small portion.
If you want to get the benefit of GPU, calculation on big array can be done in GPU. I guess the above example code uses small array, and in that case i guess simply calculating in CPU is faster.

Comment: Oh now I see your point. I have modified the code to consider random 100 detections. Still I have the same problem. I tried the @yuki-hashimoto 's answer. I tried your answer. It worked, but the speed of GPU is much slower than CPU with 10000 random detections.